# Volume render DICOMDIR CT scan

Tags: dicom

I got a CD from the hospital that is a head CD scan.

I am completely new to medical imaging. What I would like to do perform a volume rendering of the CT scan.

It is in DICOMDIR format. How and where would I start?

From messing about with various tools I get the feeling that I need to extract each series into DICOM format. Is this correct and if so how would I do it?

Comment: There's a Stack Exchange proposal for Healthcare IT, where this question may eventually make more sense.  See here:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6433/healthcare-it

Comment: Related: http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/ct-scan-software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you were given the volume data your rendering will be disappointing at best.  Many institutions still acquire head CT's in separate "step-slices", and not as volumes so here you will have significant 'stepping' artifact.
Even if it was acquired with volume data, unless they transferred all the data to your CD, you will still be stuck with only the processed 'slab' or 'slice' images.
The best way to do a volume rendering is to actually have the volume data.  "Slice image" data has most of the information dumbed down and removed.  You are just getting 20 or 30 images in 256 x 256 x (8 or 16 bit greyscale) array data.

Comment: I actually got round to doing it a year later. I used slicer to build up a volume from the slices.

Comment: [Accidentally hit the enter button.] I also used Meshlab to convert the volume to stl format. From there I got a physical prototype built: http://s14.postimage.org/z1qexnswv/proto.jpg . @NibbyX it is definitely true that fidelity is lost when using the slices. However as I had slices from the 3 different axes I could pull out some more detail when required. Also if I do get another scan done, what should I ask for in order to get the volume data? (Assuming that the lab is willing too and it will fit on a CD).

Comment: I don't support this data purity elitism. Volume data is what medics use, want and need. There are almost no use cases where volume data is insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a mac try [OsiriX](http://www.osirix-viewer.com/) - it's free, open source and will do everything you need and more. If you don't, and this is a one time thing, you could always sign up for a free demo of a commercial grade DICOM viewer. Medical image viewing software is insanely expensive and would be impossible to sell without demos. Just claim to be working for a clinician and you'll have no problem getting working software.

Comment: Yep I've used OsiriX on a mac in vmware. It's great. Unfortunately it's only a viewer not a renderer. After some more research, I think in order to create proper 3d render you would need a bit of training first.

Comment: Osirix can produce some really beautiful renders. http://www.osirix-viewer.com/OsiriX-GUI/VolumeRendering-02.jpg .. I had no formal training, but after playing for several minutes I was able to produce really similar images.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/download.html) will open any of the files in the DICOMDIR for you. I'm not entirely sure it can open the entire study from the DICOMDIR, but I'm fairly certain it will handle any individual files you need to open. It should also offer the option to export the images to various other formats. If you need more info, feel free to post a comment.

Comment: Yes I currently use imageJ. I tried using it for volume/surface rendering, but it runs out of memory. I've also realised that it takes a whole lot more than just exporting files in a different format and feeding them into a piece of software to get a 3d render.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try MevisLab (http://www.mevislab.de/) it is free but a bit more complex to use and maybe it requires two steps to get the rendering of your dicom images.
Most probably you have to use one of the widgets they provide to convert the image and then to load the converted image and render it.

Answer (score 0):

I have done with ImageJ but ImageJ not support compress dicom files at that time you have create your own logic to read compress dicom file.

 [Fiji](http://fiji.sc/Fiji)  and [VolumeJ](http://webscreen.ophth.uiowa.edu/bij/vr.htm) are also Good Option for Volume Rendering

Answer (score 0):

Try [Real3d VolViCon](http://real3d.pk/volvicon/) which is an advanced application for reconstruction of computed tomography (CT), magnetic resonance (MR), ultrasound, and x-rays images. It gives features for exporting 3D surfaces or volume as triangular mesh files for creating physical models using 3D printing technologies. It also provides high-quality visualization, linear and angular measurement tools, and various type of markups. It takes a single raw volume file or a sequence of 2D (i.e., DICOM) files and reconstructs 3D volume (voxels) and mesh (surfaces) models.